# How to remake `gcloud run deploy` with .NET Cloud Client Libraries?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, .net-5, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy an already built image to Cloud Run using .NET Cloud Client Libraries.

I need exactly the same behavior as `gcloud run deploy hello --image=us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello` but with .NET Cloud Client Libraries.

Unfortunately, I cannot find an API that does that in https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference.

I also tried downloading Cloud SDK from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install and inspecting the code with PyCharm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API is called **Cloud Run Admin API**.

[Cloud Run Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest)

There is an SDK for .NET.

[Cloud Run Admin API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/run/v1)

[Namespace Google.Apis.CloudRun.v1](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.CloudRun.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.CloudRun.v1.html)

Creating a Cloud Run service is fairly complicated. I recommend that you study the REST API first so that you understand the request body. The .NET library models the REST API.

[Method: namespaces.services.create](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/create)

The key item is the service resource:

[Resource: Service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services#Service)

There is a quick way to learn the API request body. Create a simple Cloud Run example and then add the command line option **--log-http**. Save the output to a file and then study the HTTP request parameters and request body to decipher the very large data structures that are required to create a service.

```
gcloud run deploy --log-http
```

I wrote two articles on the Cloud Run Admin API:

1. [Google Cloud Run Deep Dive – Understanding the APIs – Part 1](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-deep-dive-understanding-the-apis-part-1/)
2. [Google Cloud Run Deep Dive – Understanding the APIs – Part 2](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-deep-dive-understanding-the-apis-part-2/)

Note: I wrote those articles two years ago. Cloud Run has advanced a lot since then. However, these articles will help you understand the low-level details of the service that were not published elsewhere at the time.